# autowiring and injecting the properties using deployment by maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jetty

not able to run this and showing errors
this is on the console giving error when running on jetty it cannot autowire
all the autowiring is done here

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeService com.dineshonjava.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dineshonjava.dao.EmployeeDao com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autow
ire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dineshonjava.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:589)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2014-06-27 11:09:03.961:INFO::Opened C:\my-app1\target\2014_06_27.request.log
2014-06-27 11:09:04.008:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
2014-06-27 11:12:51.009:INFO::Shutdown hook executing
2014-06-27 11:12:51.009:INFO::Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
2014-06-27 11:12:51.618:INFO::Shutdown hook complete[INFO]
Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

here is the code for the controller and here is code for controller
    here us ee i have done all the autowiring needed

**

```
 and here is code for controller
    here us ee i have done all the autowiring needed 
    **



    package com.dineshonjava.controller;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.dineshonjava.bean.EmployeeBean;
    import com.dineshonjava.model.Employee;
    import com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeService;


    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("myproject")
    public class EmployeeController {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeService employeeService;

    /*  @Resource
        @Qualifier("employeeService")
        private EmployeeService employeeService;*/

        @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean, 
                BindingResult result) {
            Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
            employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/add.html");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView listEmployees() {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
                BindingResult result) {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView welcome() {
            return new ModelAndView("index");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
                BindingResult result) {
            employeeService.deleteEmployee(prepareModel(employeeBean));
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employee", null);
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
                BindingResult result) {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService.getEmployee(employeeBean.getId())));
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
        }

        private Employee prepareModel(EmployeeBean employeeBean){
            Employee employee = new Employee();
        //  employee.setEmpAddress(employeeBean.getAddress());
            employee.setEmpAge(employeeBean.getAge());
        //  employee.setEmpName(employeeBean.getName());
            employee.setSalary(employeeBean.getSalary());
            employee.setEmpId(employeeBean.getId());
            employeeBean.setId(null);
            return employee;
        }

        private List<EmployeeBean> prepareListofBean(List<Employee> employees){
            List<EmployeeBean> beans = null;
            if(employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()){
                beans = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
                EmployeeBean bean = null;
                for(Employee employee : employees){
                    bean = new EmployeeBean();
                //  bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
                    bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
                //  bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
                    bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
                    bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
                    beans.add(bean);
                }
            }
            return beans;
        }

        private EmployeeBean prepareEmployeeBean(Employee employee){
            EmployeeBean bean = new EmployeeBean();
        //bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
            bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
        //  bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
            bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
            bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
            return bean;
        }
    }



here is the code of the employeeService class 

    package com.dineshonjava.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dineshonjava.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.dineshonjava.model.Employee;

@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);
    }

    public List<Employee> listEmployeess() {
        return employeeDao.listEmployeess();
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(int empid) {
        return employeeDao.getEmployee(empid);
    }

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeDao.deleteEmployee(employee);
    }

}
```

**POM FILE**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-app1</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0.29</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<executable>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin/javac</executable> -->
                    <!--<source>1.6</source> -->
                    <!--<target>1.6</target> -->
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin/javac</executable>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>




            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.24</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>my-app1</stopKey>
                    <!-- Redeploy every x seconds if changes are detected, 0 for no automatic 
                        redeployment -->
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <!-- make sure Jetty also finds the widgetset -->
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/my-app1</contextPath>
                        <baseResource implementation="org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection">
                            <!-- Workaround for Maven/Jetty issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-680 -->
                            <!-- <resources>src/main/webapp,${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</resources> -->
                            <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,${project.build.directory}/classes</resourcesAsCSV>
                        </baseResource>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>logback.configurationFile</name>
                            <value>file:src/main/resources/logback-jetty.xml</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
                        <filename>${project.build.directory}/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</filename>
                        <retainDays>90</retainDays>
                        <append>true</append>
                        <extended>false</extended>
                    </requestLog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.0.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1_4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xom</groupId>
            <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-full</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.resource</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ferstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc-oracle-ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your controller per se. But it wants `EmployeeService` injected which wants something else injected, et cetera, until finally Hibernate's `SessionFactory` cannot find `CacheProvider`. You have an incomplete Hibernate on your classpath. However, `CacheProvider` should be available in Hibernate and Hibernate Core packages. Go, Maven!

Comment: here is the code for teh employee service and i am using maven for this but still getiing errors

Comment: Where is "here" :) Anyway, I don't need to see the employee service. If you want to share anything, then make it your POM file.

Comment: i have added the pom.xml here

Comment: You depend on `hibernate-entitymanager` (JPA) although your code seems to use plain Hibernate. I suggest figuring out that difference. But the fix seems to be to include `hibernate-core` as a Maven dependency.

Comment: i have included the hibernate-core as in my pom.xml still getting  the same error for autowiring

Comment: Strip out Hibernate dependencies until you have the bare minimum. I don't think you need `hibernate-entitymanager` for plain Hibernate, and there might be some others that you don't need (yet). Hibernate Core should absolutely include that `CacheProvider`. Are you sure the error you are getting is actually still the *same one*?